# The system does not start with nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, endeavouros

I installed EndeavourOS (arch) and after installing everything worked but there were no drivers. I typed `pacman -S nvidia nvidia-utils` and after rebooting the system did not boot, just a black screen. I uninstalled these packages with `arch-chroot` from the flash drive and everything was working again. I tried to install the linux-lts kernel with nvidia-lts but no success. What is the problem? Everything was working before.

GPU nvidia rtx3050.
Sddm and kde plasma.
X11.